# Register client to multiple Spring Boot Admin servers - server list and register-once=false

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am trying to register a Spring Boot application to multiple Spring Boot Admin servers using the Spring Boot Admin client.

In the [client config docs](https://docs.spring-boot-admin.com/current/client.html) it says:

`spring.boot.admin.client.url` - Comma separated ordered list of URLs of the Spring Boot Admin server to register at. This triggers the AutoConfiguration. Mandatory.

`spring.boot.admin.client.register-once` - If set to true the client will only register against one admin server (in order defined by `spring.boot.admin.instance.url`); if that admin server goes down, will automatically register against the next admin server. If false, will register against all admin servers.

I have these set as:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.url: "http://server1:port/admin/,http://server2:port/admin/"
spring.boot.admin.client.register-once: false
```

But when I launch the client app, it only registers to server1.

I am wondering if the explanation in `register-once` is incorrect in that it mentions `spring.boot.admin.instance.url` not `spring.boot.admin.client.url`. If these are different, there seems to be no reference of the former.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, which versions of Spring Boot Admin are you using? I have tested a setup using your properties for Spring Boot Admin Server 2.7. and a Client using Spring Boot 3.1.1. After removing trailing spaces as well as the double quotes, the Client was able to register as expected.

Comment: We are using SBA 3.1.x (need to check actual version). I will remove the double quotes. What trailing spaces are you referring to? That's probably a copy/paste error but I will check my actual config. Thx

Comment: @StephanKöninger I was rereading your comment... to be clear, I am trying to get a single Spring Boot app to register itself with 2 SBAs at the same time. I have no trouble getting the Spring Boot app registered with server1 but it never registers with server2